# Granite bridge between Java and AS

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, graniteds

I'm trying to create bridge between Java and ActionScript applications using Granite. I found many tutorials which guides how to build it through Flex, but is there any way to call Java services using Granite in ActionScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called Web Services.  You can't have AS called Java directly since they're not linked in any way, unless you use an Android deployment and modify the Java container, but that's another thing altogether.  You need to remember that if you're using Flash, it's using the Client-Server methodology of doing things.  They're 2 separate entities that need to communicate with each other using a certain protocol which is for the most part HTTP requests.

Comment: Is there any example or a guide about how I can implement this?

Comment: Are you asking me to actually google for you?  On the Flex side, it's very easy to point your ServiceObject to an endpoint.  Creating the java side to a WAR package to deploy is a bit more tricky and involves knowing more about how java works.  I would also recommend you look at compiling it all with Maven, but it's a requirement.  You've got lots of reading ahead of you.